# Switch between header and source files in one buffer

Tags: buffers, neovim

I am currently using [vim-altr](https://github.com/kana/vim-altr) to switch between head and source file in c++. I use

```
nmap <F2> <Plug>(altr-forward)
nmap <F3> <Plug>(altr-back)
```

to move between buffer. However, this opens two buffers. I would like it to be in one (and only one) buffer.

If this cannot be done by [vim-altr](https://github.com/kana/vim-altr), is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the terminology slightly, here. Essentially, a Vim buffer *is* a file, so loading two files into a single buffer isn't a concept that really makes sense.

It seems from your comments that the real issue is that you don't want to have both files in the *buffer list* (as displayed by vim-airline) at the same time.

I don't recommend that you do this (I think it's better to just get used to the way that Vim works), but if you *really* want to, you can achieve this by altering the mappings you use to call the altr plugin:

```
function! MySwitchForward()
  let b = bufnr("%")
  call altr#forward()
  execute "bdelete " . b
endfunction
function! MySwitchBack()
  let b = bufnr("%")
  call altr#back()
  execute "bdelete " . b
endfunction

nmap <F2> :call MySwitchForward()<CR>
nmap <F3> :call MySwitchBack()<CR>
```

These mappings use `altr` to switch buffers, and then delete the buffer you just switched away from.

N.B. In my testing with the `a.vim` plugin, this approach didn't work well, because of the method `a.vim` uses for opening the buffer. I'm pretty sure it *will* work with the altr plugin you are using, but if not, you will need to replace "bdelete" with "bwipeout" (although make sure you are aware of [the consequences](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/) before doing so).

Comment: Having been learning a lot more about buffers vs tabs, your assertion that I was confused by the two is indeed correct.

Comment: The problem is that I can have half a dozen source files open, with all the headers that's a dozen files… It's getting hard to see what is where.

Comment: @Sardathrion My personal feeling is that you'd be better off by leaving the buffers alone, and instead stop displaying them all in vim-airline. If that doesn't work for you, though, then the mappings in my answer are the only real solution.

Comment: Yes, I am coming to the same conclusion. Although, I would like to display tabs since that way I can see what pairs of files I have opened.

Comment: @Sardathrion If you *do* decide to try turning off permanent buffer display, you may also find the answers to [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9156/) and [this one](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/) helpful.

Comment: @Sardathrion [And this one!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082991/)

Comment: I actually would rather learn how vim does it properly instead of hacking stuff that were not meant to be… ⍨

Comment: I often open a dozen pair of windows for header file + implementation file. I display them side by side (thanks to a.vim `:AV` command). Then I navigate with a tag explorer plugin (there are plenty). In all cases, I never invest any attention to the buffers that are opened/loaded.

Comment: @Sardathrion As Luc Hermitte suggests, the standard vimmy way is not to care which buffers are loaded. The question to ask yourself is "why do I need the list displayed onscreen at all times?". If you don't have a good answer, then try turning it off! [Here's another good resource](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/what-can-i-do-with-more-tabs-than-fit-in-one-airline-tab-line). If you *do* have a good answer, maybe there is another way of achieving the same goal, using the functionality Vim already provides.

Comment: If you do really need all the buffers listed onscreen, you might prefer [minibufexplorer](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) to airline's display: it uses multiple lines when the list is long.

Answer (score 0):

The venerable alternate plugin ([a.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31)), has a `:A` command that seems to be exactly what you're looking for -- changing the buffer currently displayed in the current window, however you'll see several buffers with `:ls`.

Its API is a little bit cumbersome though and it doesn't provide a neat way to have different settings for different projects -- I guess this is why several other similar plugins have emerged since then.

Comment: Hum, I get the same behaviour. Although, I am using vim-airline buffer display so I guess it shows all the buffers which makes sense…